# loadUpdateData always inserting whole CSV

Tags: liquibase

I want to be able to edit the contents of my CSV file and every time there is a change it to, the appropriate records be added/modified/deleted.

Using loadUpdateData coupled with runOnChange="true", each time there is a change in the CSV, the entire CSV contents are re-inserted to the DB causing lots of duplicates.

Using liquibase maven plugin 3.0.5 with MySql Community Server 5.7

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

<changeSet author="foobar" id="fizzbuzzDataLoad"  runOnChange="true">
    <loadUpdateData
            encoding="UTF-8"
            file="src/main/resources/liquibase/fizzbuzz.csv"
            quotchar=""
            separator=","
            primaryKey="ïntA"
            tableName="fizzbuzz">
        <column name="intA" type="NUMERIC"/>
        <column name="output" type="STRING"/>
    </loadUpdateData>
</changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**Example**

Initial state of file --> All rows inserted when table was empty:

```
intA,Output
1,1
2,2
3,FIZZ
4,4
5,BUZZ
6,FIZZ
```

New row added --> All rows inserted again

```
7,7
```

DB looks like this:

```
  intA  Output
    1   1
    2   2
    3   FIZZ
    4   4
    5   BUZZ
    6   FIZZ
    1   1
    2   2
    3   FIZZ
    4   4
    5   BUZZ
    6   FIZZ
    7   7
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Silly me, intA was not marked as primary key in its create table changelog. That fixed the immediate problem. It will update values if it detects a key collision.

That said, if I delete a row from the CSV, it remains in the DB. I've worked around this by having Liquibsae always truncate the table and then run loadData to insert all data fresh.

```
<changeSet author="fooBar" id="fizzbuzzDataClear"
        runAlways="true">
        <delete tableName="fizzBuzz">
        </delete>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="fooBar" id="fizzbuzzDataLoad"
        runAlways="true">
        <loadUpdateData encoding="UTF-8"
            file="src/main/resources/liquibase/data/fizzbuzz.csv" quotchar=""
            separator="," primaryKey="ïntA" tableName="fizzbuzz">
            <column name="intA" type="NUMERIC" />
            <column name="output" type="STRING" />
        </loadUpdateData>
    </changeSet>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the onlyUpdate="true" which would update if records found and ignores if not found

Answer (score 0):

loadUpdateData is behaving as designed. Liquibase does not support detecting changes in data in tables.

Comment: I'm not changing the table, but changing the CSV file. Assuming that is what you meant, how then do I interpret this statement from the loadDataUpdate doc page: "Loads or updates data from a CSV file into an existing table. Differs from loadData by issuing a SQL batch that checks for the existence of a record. If found, the record is UPDATEd, else the record is INSERTed"

Comment: Cool - I was not aware of this feature!

Is the intA column in the table actually a primary key?

Comment: Silly me, intA was not marked as primary key in it's create table statement. That fixed the immediate problem. It will update values if it detects a key collision. That said, if I delete a row from the CSV, it remains in the DB. I've worked around this by having Liquibsae always truncate the table and then run loadData to insert all data fresh.